# Baye's rule - how to calculate likelihood

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, probability, bayesian

Given is some data, `data`, which corresponds to a binary sequence of coin flips, where heads are 1's and tails are 0's. Theta is a value between 0 and 1 representing the probability that a coin produces heads when flipped.

How does one go about calculating the likelihood? I faintly remember a formula where:

```
likelihood = (theta)^(h)*(1-theta)^(1-h)
```

where h is 1 if heads, and 0 if tails. I implemented the following code:

```
import numpy as np
(np.prod([theta*1 for i in data if i==1]) * np.prod([1-theta for i in data if i==0]))
```

This code works for some cases but not for some hidden cases (so I'm not sure what's wrong with it).

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways to interpret what you are trying to calculate:

1. Probability of exactly that sequence, including the order in which the head occurs (which is how your question is posed here)
2. Probability of the number of heads (lets call this `X`) occurring in your sequence, regardless of the order (which is what I think you were asking for).

**option 1:**

```
import numpy as np
theta = 0.2      # Probability of H is 0.2, hence NOT a fair coin
data = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]     # T, H, T, H, H, .... 


def likelihood(theta, h):
    return (theta)**(h)*(1-theta)**(1-h)

likelihood(theta, 1) # 0.2
likelihood(theta, 0) # 0.8

singlethrow = [likelihood(theta, x) for x in data]
prob1 = np.prod(singlethrow)    # 2.6214400000000015e-05
```

`prob1` will converge to zero pretty quickly, because every additional coin toss will multiply the existing probability with a number smaller than 1 (either 0.2 if heads, 0.8 if tails)

**option 2:**

is a binomial distribution. This adds up the probability of all possible outcomes that results in a total of, say, 6 heads when tossing a coin 10 times. One particular sequence that results in 6 heads for 10 tosses we already evaluated in option 1 above. There are 210 such ways ( = 10! / (6!*(10−6)!)  )

The `scipy.stats.binom.pmf()` functionality calculates this probability for you:

```
import scipy, scipy.stats
prob2 = scipy.stats.binom.pmf(6, 10, theta)
```

Or, more generally, if you rely on `data` in the form I defined above:

```
X = sum([toss == 1 for toss in data])
N = len(data)
prob3 = scipy.stats.binom.pmf(X, N, theta)

prob2 == prob3   # True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in the Bayesian approach, you might want to have a look at the `conjugate_prior` package

```
from conjugate_prior import BetaBinomial
prior_model = BetaBinomial(1,1) # Uninformative prior
updated_model = prior_model.update(heads, tails)
credible_interval = updated_model.posterior(0.45, 0.55)
print ("There's {p:.2f}% chance that the coin is fair".format(p=credible_interval*100))
```

Comment: Apparently the question had been removed